# Get data from several series Highcharts

Tags: json, highcharts, series

I'm trying to display a Highcharts graphic with 2 series to compare data.

I'm using the following javascript code:

```
$(function () {
$.getJSON('test.php', function (data, data2) {

    // create the chart
    $('#container').highcharts('StockChart', {
        chart: {
            alignTicks: false
        },

        rangeSelector: {
            selected: 1
        },

        title: {
            text: 'AAPL Stock Volume'
        },
    plotOptions: {
        column: {
            stacking: 'normal',

        }
    },
        series: [{
            type: 'column',

            name: 'AAPL Stock Volume',
            data: data,
            dataGrouping: {
                units: [[
                    'week', // unit name
                    [1] // allowed multiples
                ], [
                    'month',
                    [1, 2, 3, 4, 6]
                ]]
            }
        },{

            type: 'column',
            name: 'AAPL Stock Volume',
            data: data,
            dataGrouping: {
                units: [[
                    'week', // unit name
                    [1] // allowed multiples
                ], [
                    'month',
                    [1, 2, 3, 4, 6]
                ]]
            }
        }]
    });
});
```

});

and this PHP code:

```
$arr = array([1147651200000,1],[1147737600000,3],[1147824000000,1]);

$arr2 = array([1147651200000,1],[1147737600000,3],[1147824000000,1]);

echo json_encode($arr, $arr2);?>
```

For the moment, all I have is a blank page but if transmit only one array, it works.

I made different tests and my problem is the json_encode function takes only one parameter. My question is the following: How to transmit the two arrays to the php file ?

Comment: Put the two arrays into another array?

Answer (score 0):

I finally solved my problem. Thank's John Zwinck for the idea.

```
$(function () {
$.getJSON('test.php', function (data) {

    console.log(data);

    // create the chart
    $('#container').highcharts('StockChart', {
        chart: {
            alignTicks: false
        },

        rangeSelector: {
            selected: 1
        },

        title: {
            text: 'AAPL Stock Volume'
        },
    plotOptions: {
        column: {
            stacking: 'normal',

        }
    },
        series: [{
            type: 'column',

            name: 'AAPL Stock Volume',
            data: data.arr1,
            dataGrouping: {
                units: [[
                    'week', // unit name
                    [1] // allowed multiples
                ], [
                    'month',
                    [1, 2, 3, 4, 6]
                ]]
            }
        },{

            type: 'column',
            name: 'AAPL Stock Volume',
            data: data.arr2,
            dataGrouping: {
                units: [[
                    'week', // unit name
                    [1] // allowed multiples
                ], [
                    'month',
                    [1, 2, 3, 4, 6]
                ]]
            }
        }]
    });
});
```

});

```
$arr1 = array([1147651200000,4],[1147737600000,3],[1147824000000,6]);

$arr2 = array([1147651200000,4],[1147737600000,8],[1147824000000,2]);

echo json_encode(array('arr1' => $arr1, 'arr2' => $arr2));
```